# Asp.Net Core - Explicitly setting the controller name in routing does not work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following in an Asp.Net Core 3.1

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Test", pattern: "test/{action}").RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute());
});
```

If I call

```
http://localhost:8866/test/test
http://localhost:8866/test/test2
```

I get 404.

How can I specify all actions under the test controller must work as possible routes?

Answer (score 0):

*--Post edited after comments beacuse could be measliding--*

Try posting your TestController

Comment: There is no option MapRoute

Comment: Maybe you can post the controller file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing the values for the controller instead of directly hardcoding the controller value?

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Test",
                    pattern: "{controller=Test}/{action=Index}");
            });
```